# How can you remove the last character from a wchar_t*?

Tags: c++

How can I delete the last character of a wchar_t* and resize accordingly?  For example, having the string "test" and bringing it down to "tes"

Answer (score 11):

How about `str[wcslen(str) - 1] = '\0'`

Make sure the string is at least 1 character long first though!

Comment: Or you can be completely pedantic and write `L'\0'`.

Comment: Or 0 - the literal has type `int` instead of `char` or `wchar_t`, but it converts to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please explain what you mean by "resize accordingly"? Do you want to resize the buffer that was allocated? (Even if you think you do, you probably don't, because resizing to shave one character will probably throw the memory allocator off, but I think I should ask anyway)